# sql one query to choose max/min for selected identifiers (some kind of for each?)

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have simple sql structure:

```
CREATE TABLE main_tbl(
                id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC,
                start_time TEXT NOT NULL,
                );

CREATE TABLE second_tbl (
                id     INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                data   BLOB,
                m_id   INTEGER NOT NULL,
                FOREIGN KEY(m_id) REFERENCES main_tbl(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
                );

CREATE INDEX m_id_idx ON second_tbl (m_id);
CREATE INDEX start_time_idx ON main_tbl (start_time);
```

And want to find some items from `main_tbl`:

`SELECT id,start_time FROM main_tbl ORDER BY start_time DESC LIMIT X OFFSET Y;`

and then for selected set of `main_tbl.id` find min/max:

```
  SELECT data FROM second_tbl WHERE m_id=chosen_id AND SOME_CONDITION ORDER BY second_tbl.id ASC LIMIT 1
  UNION
  SELECT data FROM second_tbl WHERE m_id=chosen_id AND SOME_CONDITION ORDER BY second_tbl.id DESC LIMIT 1
```

On pseudo language it looks like this:

```
foreach chosen_id IN (SELECT id,start_time FROM main_tbl ORDER BY start_time DESC LIMIT X OFFSET Y)
  SELECT data FROM second_tbl WHERE m_id=chosen_id AND SOME_CONDITION ORDER BY second_tbl.id ASC LIMIT 1
  UNION
  SELECT data FROM second_tbl WHERE m_id=chosen_id AND SOME_CONDITION ORDER BY second_tbl.id DESC LIMIT 1
```

But how to write this in one SQL query (sqlite subset of SQL actually)?

If I write:

```
WITH chosen_ids(id,data) AS (SELECT id,start_time FROM main_tbl ORDER BY start_time DESC LIMIT X OFFSET Y)
  SELECT data FROM second_tbl WHERE m_id IN (SELECT id from chosen_ids) AND SOME_CONDITION ORDER BY second_tbl.id ASC LIMIT 1
```

than I get mininim for all `chosen_ids` while I need for each of them.

If I use `JOIN` instead of `WITH` I can only set `LIMIT/OFFSET` for whole JOIN query not only for `SELECT` from `main_tbl`.

**Update**

Example data:

```sql
sqlite> SELECT id,start_time FROM main_tbl ORDER BY start_time DESC LIMIT 5 OFFSET 100;
900|2019-03-14T08:36:26.324937205+00:00
899|2019-03-14T06:36:26.324937205+00:00
898|2019-03-14T04:36:26.324937205+00:00
897|2019-03-14T02:36:26.324937205+00:00
896|2019-03-14T00:36:26.324937205+00:00
```

then I have run subqueries for 896-900, here is example for 900:

```sql
sqlite> SELECT quote(data) FROM second_tbl WHERE m_id=900 AND data IS NOT NULL ORDER BY second_tbl.id ASC LIMIT 1;
X'000000008A128A5C00000000F5255E13000000000000F03F0000000000000040000000000000084000000000000010400000000000001440010000000000001840'


sqlite> SELECT quote(data) FROM second_tbl WHERE m_id=900 AND data IS NOT NULL ORDER BY second_tbl.id DESC LIMIT 1;
X'00000000AA2E8A5C00000000F544680D000000000000F03F0000000000000040000000000000084000000000000010400000000000001440010000000000001840'
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be really helpful.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I update my question with example data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can write this as one query using:

```
SELECT m.id, m.start_time, MIN(s.data) as min_data, MAX(s.data) as max_data
FROM main_tbl m LEFT JOIN
     second_tbl s
     ON s.m_id = m.id
GROUP BY m.id
ORDER BY start_time DESC
LIMIT X OFFSET Y;
```

EDIT:

You can use correlated subqueries:

```
SELECT m.id, m.start_time, 
       (SELECT s.data FROM second_tbl s WHERE m.m_id = s.chosen_id AND SOME_CONDITION ORDER BY s.id ASC LIMIT 1) as min_data,
       (SELECT s.data FROM second_tbl s WHERE m.m_id = s.chosen_id AND SOME_CONDITION ORDER BY s.id DESC LIMIT 1) as max_data
FROM main_tbl m 
ORDER BY start_time DESC
LIMIT X OFFSET Y;
```

Comment: I need MIN not for data, see I do `ORDER BY second_tbl.id ASC/DESC LIMIT 1` plus for min/max search I choose only some rows (this is `SOME_CONDITION`), but may be this is not important. Let me think about this.

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason the second query return the same `m.id` for each row?  I replace `m.m_id = s.chosen_id` with `m.id = s.m_id` and run your query, but for some reason, it reports `X (LIMIT)` times the same `m.id`